# Categorize wordpress pages and restrict editors to certain pages/categories

Tags: wordpress

We have a huge WordPress website and looking for a solution to manage the maintainers.

The goal is to let editors be free to edit pages in certain categories but shouldn't be able to mess up the whole site.

Edit:
I found out, that you can achieve this by using [role scoper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of WordPress plugin called ***Edit Flow***. It does more than what you need.